# EF Core calculated property produces inefficient query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a class that has a couple of fields

```
public bool IsX { get;set; }

public bool IsY { get; set; }

public bool IsZ => IsX || IsY;
```

Rather than having to remember to query against the entity being a either X or Y every time, I wanted to add the helper that would do that for me (given that X and Y are really a subsets of Z.

But when I run this and look at the SQL produced for a count where IsZ.  It will select all properties and all records, then seems to do the count in memory.  Where as if I do a count where IsX OR IsY it will simply count(*) and apply the correct where clause.

I am not sure what configuration this needs, or how to set it up so it queries the database nicely.  I would rather not add the column to the database, if I can avoid it, (seems cleaner for the DB to just have the fields I am actually setting).

Is there a way to do this, or should I change it to a more normal property that somehow sets it self?

Answer (score 1):

EF requires an expression tree in order to translate the predicate into something that can be executed on the database server. This may not be as clean as it is in your question, but a solution to your problem could look something like this:

```
public static class MyDatabaseObjectHelpers
{
    public static Expression<Func<MyDatabaseObject, bool>> IsZ = d => d.IsX || d.IsY;
}
```

Then, your database queries would look like this:

```
var zCount = context.MyDatabaseObjects.Where(IsZ).Count();
```

Since IsZ is an expression the translator will be able to recognize that all conditions are able to be processed on the db server.